# ASP.NET WebAPI and Razor Pages in the same web location

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I've developed a project that consisted of just a WebApi, which was deployed through VS WebDeploy at the root of the webspace.
With new requirements, I also needed to host a webapp in the same webspace (Razor pages).
I decided to keep the projects separated in my Visual Studio Solution, and publish the API into the `{root}/webapi/` folder, and the Razor webapp in the `{root}` folder.

I started by republishing the webapi into the new folder location and making a test API call (adding the folder location as part of the url, so http:/example.com/**webapi**/route), but the Server returned `Server Error in '/' Application. Runtime Error`.

I wonder if there's some other parameter that needs to be changed when moving the project to a subfolder, and any other solution to the problem I'm trying to tackle is welcome.

PS: I don't have access to the IIS Server settings of the hosting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert at hosting .NET Core apps on IIS but chances are that you can't make this setup work if you're not allowed to change the IIS Server configuration. I assume you need to add your nested API project as a Website to make IIS actually run it.

So, it looks like you need some kind of multi-tenancy. As your question is about Razor Pages, I presume we are dealing with ASP.NET Core here instead of classic ASP.NET (suggested by your tags).

In ASP.NET Core it's pretty easy to setup multi-tenant applications using [application branches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#use-run-and-map). In this case your *Startup.Configure* method of your main Razor Pages project would look like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Map("/webapi", ConfigureWebApiBranch);

    // configuration of your Razor Pages app pipeline...

    app.UseMvc(...);
}

public void ConfigureWebApiBranch(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // configuration of your Web Api app pipeline...

    app.UseMvc(...);
}
```

Of course, *ConfigureWebApiBranch* can reside in another assembly so you can keep the two projects logically separated.

There's one gotcha regarding this solution. Both the main and the web api branch shares the same DI container configured in *Startup.ConfigureServices* of your main project. But this can be fixed, as well, if necessary. You find a detailed explanation of this e.g. [here](https://www.strathweb.com/2017/04/running-multiple-independent-asp-net-core-pipelines-side-by-side-in-the-same-application/).

Comment: Thanks @Adam Simon, from how you wrote the first sentence, it seems feasible to do that if I stick to .NET (using MVC instead of Razor), am I correct? Or conversely moving the current API to ASP.NET Core

Comment: If you want to adopt the multi-tenant solution I described, you obviously can't mix up platorms. Both projects must be run on either classic ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core. My answer focuses on the latter but it's possible to have MVC and WebApi side by side in a single application in classic ASP.NET, as well.